# What is the jQuery equivalent for this method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how would you call `document.body.innerText;` and `document.body.innerHTML;` in jQuery. How does jQuery handle javascript methods that start with document.body...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
// document.body.innerText;
$('body').text();
```

[.text() docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
//document.body.innerHTML;
$('body').html();
```

[.html() docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 4):

Here they are -- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

`$("body").text()` and `$("body").html()`.

Comment: document.body == $(body)  what about window.something

Comment: @Mike: That comment looks totally wrong. First of all no DOM element is `== $(...)` ever. Then `body` is not defined. It's `'body'` or `document.body`

Comment: @Mike: Well, `window.something` is `window.something`, there is no need in jQuery, since jQuery helps to manipulate DOM elements but was not invented for working with objects.

Comment: it would be `$(window)`, and since window has an onload property, you can do `$(window).load(function(){ // window has loaded })`

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('body')` or `$(document.body)` to select the body. Then you can use `.text()` and `.html()` to get the related contents.

Answer (score 1):

`$("id/class/name/document")` is to select and you can use the `html()` (innerhtml
) and `text()` (innertext
) to there contents.

1- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
<div class="demo">Demonstration Box</div>

The code $('.demo').text() would produce the following result:
```

this is to select--^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^---to content of class `demo`

output:

```
 Demonstration Box
```

2- [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
                      <div class="demo"><p>Demonstration Box</p></div>

$("input").html("text"); will change the---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---to text
```

Comment: # = id   #div1
. = class .bigButtons
and just the tag text to select any of that tag these selectors are the same as CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').text(); // innertext
$('body').html();//innerhtml
```